# Dynamic Virtual Hosts In Apache with www and non-www subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2

I don't know apache very well and I've got a problem with configure `mod_vhost_alias`

This is my httpd.conf file:

```
UseCanonicalName Off

LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon

<Directory /var/www/sites/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    CustomLog logs/access_log.sites vcommon
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/sites/%1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Subdomains work fine without www. but I need to make them work with www too.

Here's an example:

```
something.domain.com - site is loading
www.something.domain.com - Not Found
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/sites/%1/` is looking at the first part of the name - so for `something.domain.com` it's using `something`, and for `www.something.domain.com` it's using `www`, which won't work very well.

A couple different options:

1. Get it to use `something` as the directory it's looking for in both cases; instead of the first part of the name, look at the third-to-last:

   ```
   VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/sites/%-3/
   ```
2. Switch over to using the full name, and then create a symbolic link (see Michael's answer):

   ```
   VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/sites/%0/
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure where should I create that link (you can write for future) but `%-3` did the trick. Thanks man.

Comment: @haukish You'd do it in `/var/www/sites`, so inside there you would have `something.domain.com` (the real directory) and `www.something.domain.com` (the symbolic link).

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but in this case I'll have to do it every time I create new directory for new subdomain. Am I right? `%-3` seems to work right, but I'll keep it in my mind, thx again.

Comment: @haukish Yup, you'd need a new link for every sub-domain.  The trade-off is that `%-3` will break if you add an extra level to the subdomains - so `www.one.some.domain.com` and `two.some.domain.com` will both use `some` - the extra layers would be ignored.

Comment: I think I wouldn't need next level on this domain but thanks for mention

Answer (score 2):

`something.domain.com` and `www.something.domain.com` are obviously different hostnames. And Apache will substitute this for `%1` when looking for the files to serve. So the problem is that `/var/www/sites/www.something.domain.com` doesn't exist.

One way to fix it (assuming these two sites are supposed to serve the same data) is by a simple symbolic link:

```
ln -s something.domain.com /var/www/sites/www.something.domain.com
```

(I also missed that you need `%0` instead of `%1`, as in Shane Madden's answer. So do that too.)

Comment: I believe it looks for "www.something". Can I add something like `ln -s *.domain.com /var/www/sites/www.*.domain.com` I need it for more than one domain. And where should I put it?

Comment: If it did, you would have gotten a 404 for something. and your site for www.something.

Comment: I created `www.something.domain.com` and `www.something` directories in `/var/www/sites` but there is still 404 :/